# Mixing conditions in Linux timer

Tags: systemd-timer

I want to create a timer that fires, completes execution, waits for 30 seconds and fires again but only during night hours. So far I got this:

```
[Timer]
OnUnitInactiveSec=30s
OnCalendar= * - * - * 23,24,00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07:*
```

But I don't know if the 2 conditions act as an "and" or as an "or", in other words, I don't know if one condition met will suffice to fire the timer or both would be required (which is what I want). I couldn't find that detail in the help pages and the examples I found in internet use only one type of this conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [`systemd.timer`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html):

> Multiple directives may be combined of the same and of different types, in which case the timer unit will trigger whenever any of the
> specified timer expressions elapse. For example, by combining OnBootSec= and OnUnitActiveSec=, it is possible to define a timer that elapses
> in regular intervals and activates a specific service each time. Moreover, both monotonic time expressions and OnCalendar= calendar
> expressions may be combined in the same timer unit.

The "any" specification suggests that it's an "OR" relationship.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I missed that. Well, I guess it's not possible to do what I want just setting the [Timer] configuration :(